# Duda con Bitbucket y Android studio

Tags: git

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con otra persona, y tenemos un repositorio en bitbucket donde vamos haciendo los commits, pero resulta que tenemos un problema, yo no puedo actualizar el codigo que el modifica en su maquina y el no puede actualizar el codigó que yo modifico en mi maquina,  cuando clickeo la opcion `pull` me sale el siguiente error

> Git Pull Failed
>
> Your local changes would be overwritten by merge. Commit, stash or
> revert them to proceed. View them

Comment: Parace que tu tienes otra versión adelante del codigo de tu compañero, lo que necesitas hacer es un commit a tus cambios, y despues intentar dar el pull

Comment: Suena también a que están trabajando bajo el mismo branch, lo ideal sería que aparte del branch `default` tengan cada uno su branch: `nicolas` y `amigo-de-nicolas`

Comment: me podrias explicar como hacer eso de los branchs por favor?

Comment: Aqui esta lo oficial https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-b%C3%A1sicos-para-ramificar-y-fusionar  y este es un articulo de un tercero http://www.genbetadev.com/herramientas/manejo-de-ramas-de-desarrollo-con-git creo que ambos te serviran

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt podrías agregar cual es tu procedimiento, porque estamos suponiendo, yo creo que no debe ocasionar problemas aún si haces un push al branch!.

Comment: Elena, lo pude solucionar, tenia un problema en un archivo llamado app.iml . se habia como sobreescribido y no me dejaba hace el pull. borre ese archivo ya que lo tenia 2 veces y pude actualizar el codigo.

Comment: ok Nicolas, podrías incluso agregar tu respuesta para ayudar a otros usuarios :)

Answer (score 1):

El problema estaba en el archivo app.iml, el archivo ( no se porque ) lo tenia 2 veces, entonces me tiraba error. Se borra uno de los archivos, dejando el otro en la misma carpeta y solucionado.